# Compilation error Multiple version of JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-8

I am having the below issue when I run my maven build in eclipse. I saw many posts like this but i still can't solve this problem .Mine may be a little more specific, I know that my JAVA_HOME is pointed to java6, and that is because I am working on another application which uses java 6. The application in which I am running into issues uses Java 8

```
 [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------- 
 [ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\..\lib\tools.jar Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required). .In most cases you can change the location of your Java installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable. [INFO] 1 error 
 <br>[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------- 
 <br>[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 <br>[INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 <br>[INFO] Total time: 11:53 min [INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-18T16:52:13+05:30 
 <br>[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/141M 
 <br>[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 <br>[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project 
 Compilation failure [ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in: [ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\..\lib\tools.jar 
 [ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and [ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required). 
 <br>[ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java [ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable. 
 [ERROR] -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile
```

How can I resolve this problem without installing java 8 as it may may make changes to my JAVA_HOME etc which would make my other application to not run. Is there a way to get the JDK folder without running the .exe (p.s I already tried the 7zip method) 
Please suggest

Comment: You can copy it from an other computer

Comment: you can download the `.exe`, unzip it, and then run the [`unpack200`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/unpack200.html) tool (coming with it) to unpack the `.pack` files into `.jar` libraries, then it will work just fine.

Comment: @A_Di-Matteo, How do I Unzip it?

Comment: can you psot your `pom.xml` ?

Comment: don't download the `.exe` sorry, download the `tar.gz`, it's available for Windows as well, you can simply unpack it with 7zip then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the jdk8 then you can open cmd, run the command in this window to modify the JAVA_HOME `set JAVA_HOME=<jdk8 path>`. This will modify the JAVA_HOME env variable only for this instance of the cmd session and not for the whole OS. Now run the maven build command from this window and it wont fail.

If you wanna run the build from eclipse, then in eclipse try going to Windows --> Preferences --> Java --> Installed JREs --> click Add button --> Sel Standard VM and click next --> put in values for 'JRE Home' as path till the jdk folder and 'JRE Name' as java8 or whatever you wish --> click Finish.
Now right click the project of you interest --> click properties --> Java Compiler --> Tick 'Enable project specific settings' --> and select 1.8 here.
If 1.8 is not visible here, go to Java Build Path --> Add Library --> JRE System Library --> Alternate JRE --> select jdk8 --> Finish

Comment: This would have been a good solution had I run build from cmd window. I am running maven from eclipse

Comment: Within Eclipse, what's important for the maven build is only that the launch configuration for that build refers to a JDK, not a JRE. Making a JDK your default JRE should resolve that for all future launch configurations. Changing project settings should not be needed here.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann - I recommended project specific setting because of the following line in the question: "I am working on another application which uses java 6". It was only this app which required java8.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann - The user doesn't event want to change the JAVA_HOME, so I assumed he doesnt want to change the eclipse default jdk

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the path in that error (`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\..\lib\tools.jar`) you've installed the Java Runtime Environment (JRE).

To compile java you need the Java Development Kit (JDK) which contains the tools the maven plugin needs.

Comment: Or your JAVA_HOME points to the JRE instead of the JDK. In both case, the answer is use a JDK instead of a JRE to build your project

Answer (score 1):

from your error log it says that

`[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in: [ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\..\lib\tools.jar`

paste this code in your `pom.xml` inside `build` tag and make sure you add dependencies properly and please change your `java version accordingly`

this will only work if you have something wrong in your `pom.xml`.

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.8</source>
<target>1.8</target>
<verbose>true</verbose>
<fork>true</fork>
<executable>${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
<compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.2</version>
<configuration>
<jvm>${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java</jvm>
<forkMode>once</forkMode>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

**note** your `JAVA_HOME` must point like this

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65`

**edit**

There must be various reasons like

your pom is not getting path to java home

your java home is not set

you are using `jre` instead of `jdk` in your `IDE`

Answer (score 1):

You can change your maven-compiler-plugin configurations to your **JAVA_HOME**.
Just go to eclipse **window**->**preferences**->type maven->and you could see something like **template** click on that and look for **javac** **compiler**, just go there and change to whatever java version you have.

```
     <configuration>
      <!-- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/ -->
      <source>${cursor}1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
     </configuration>
```

Without java8 and without .exe file you can't go ahead with your requirement.
Hope it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the version of the JDK without installer.
Then specify a JDK 1.8 as source and target in the compiler configuration of the pom.xml with which you have your problem. in this way you don't need changing your `JAVA_HOME` :

```
<build>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>      
            <fork>true</fork>
            <executable>D:\jdk1.8\bin\javac</executable>                
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
<build>
```

Comment: `D:\jdk1.8\bin\javac` you still need to install java

Answer (score 0):

I followed steps in the below link to get the portable JDK:
http://bgasparotto.com/convert-jdk-exe-zip/